# Что могут делать сайты?

Tags: защита, безопасность

Привет. Недавно столкнулся с одним голосованием на сайте, в котором не получалось проголосовать 2 раза ни поменяв браузер, ни зайдя через анонимайзер... Владелец сайта сказал, что заказывал эту защиту, а на вопрос "как она работает?" сказал, что она(защита) "скачивает хрень на комп, чтоб с него нельзя 2ой раз было". Разве такое возможно? Без моего ведома, и ведома антивируса, что-то загрузить? Мне кажется меня разводят...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если же "скачивает хрень на комп" - то это очень похоже нa flash cookies, как раз с помощью их можно сохранять сессию заходя из разных браузеров.

Comment: спасибо, погуглю

Answer (score 1):

Конечно , ваш браузер же поддерживает cookies.

Comment: Ну не держите меня за идиота...  "ни поменяв браузер" - с каких пор у нас одни куки на два браузера разных? и тем более, что я сразу после голосования очистил все куки.  Я поменял браузер, и полез через анонимайзер голосовать. У меня ничего не вышло.

Comment: Сори. Вопрос не читай сразу отвечай.

Answer (score 1):

А можно ссылку на этот сайт.А так предотвратить повторное голосование можно:

- Разместив соответствующие куки на компьютере.
- Сохранив айпи компьютера в базе данных.

Другие пути мне не известны.И первый решается сменой браузера, а второй сменой прокси (анонимайзер видимо подобное делает).
Так же можете попробывать зайти туда через http://www.proxfree.com интересно, что тогда получится =)

Comment: К сожалению там голосование уже закончилось, так бы я конечно дал ссылку. Я могу отписаться, если у них ещё будут голосования.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это [Evercookie](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104725/).